# Test iPhone app

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

Hi I just finished developing an iPhone app on xcode. I do have the $99 dev program. I tested the app on iPhone simulator and actual device (iPad), and it seems to be OK and the program is running well. My question, how I can send this app to my client (out of country) for review before I actually publish it to apple store?

I tried to publish the IPA, and tested on the iPad device that I used and it seems is not working? is there any link step by step to do this correctly?

Comment: good tutorial http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wAdV16nRLp8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want your app to be released to your client(s) only, you can use testflight. 
Checkout here the guidelines for it

http://changhoward.blogspot.in/2012/02/ios-developer-how-to-use-testflight-to.html[testflight guidelines](http://changhoward.blogspot.in/2012/02/ios-developer-how-to-use-testflight-to.html)

Here you can release your .ipa file..

If you want .app file to release you can check out [diawi for .app](http://www.diawi.com/)

& there are so many other ways to do this.But you will find these better, for both .ipa & .app respectively

Enjoy Programming!!

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer. testflight my upload is not successful, and diawi installation is not working, is there other link I should try?

Comment: testflight will provide you the query for why your ipa didn't get successfull

Answer (score 1):

There is a great resource named 'Test Flight'. As long as you have the Device ID number for the devices you hope to test on, you can send your app to anyone.

https://testflightapp.com/

Happy Testing!

Answer (score 0):

You must Enroll in the Apple dev program to be able to distribute, even for AD-Hoc distributions.

For AD-Hoc distributions you'll need to register every device, For that you'll need the UDID of the device.